# PHP displaying "no results" if an array is empty

Tags: php, search

I am trying to make a search script for my website. It's all going well so far, but I want to display "There are no results to display" if there are no results from the search. I tried this:

```
<?php

while($resultsarray(mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult))//$searchresult is the result of my MySQL query
{
    if($_GET['options']=='user') {
        echo "<a href = 'userinfo.php?id=".$resultsarray['usernum']."'>".$resultsarray['username']."</a>";
    }
    else if($_GET['options']=='topics') {
        echo "<a href = 'display_post.php?id=".$resultsarray['id']."'>".$resultsarray['subject']."</a>";
        echo "<p>".$resultsarray['content']."</p>";
    }
}

if(empty($resultsarray)) {
    echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
}
```

But that always displayed the message, even if there were results. I also tried this:

```
<?php

$resultsarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult);
if(empty($resultsarray)) {
    echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
}
while($resultsarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult))//$searchresult is the result of my MySQL query
{
    if($_GET['options']=='user') {
        echo "<a href = 'userinfo.php?id=".$resultsarray['usernum']."'>".$resultsarray['username']."</a>";
    }
    else if($_GET['options']=='topics') {
        echo "<a href = 'display_post.php?id=".$resultsarray['id']."'>".$resultsarray['subject']."</a>";
        echo "<p>".$resultsarray['content']."</p>";
    }
}
```

But that didn't work either. Any help with this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($resultsarray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to determine how many results were returned:

```
if ( !mysql_num_rows($searchresult) ) {
    echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
}
```

In your current code, you lose the first result row because you are calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` once and discarding the result. Using the method above, you can  eliminate the line that causes you to lose one result:

```
$resultsarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult);
```

Be aware that the `mysql_*` function are deprecated. Please consider updating your code to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I know about mysql_* but this is a home project with many pages. To be honest, i can't be bothered to convert it.

Comment: No worries about mysql_. Some people are unaware and are using it in production code, so I threw it in as a freebie. Good luck on your project!

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I've seen so many new users use it in their code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(! $resultsarray) {
    echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
}
```